# JavaFX: scaling of line chart with great values does not work

Tags: javafx, linechart

On the first picture it is visible in the x-axis that every certain amount of time there is a new data point. So here I chose an interval of 5.

[image]

If I chose an interval of 1000 then the scaling does not work properly as you can see it on the following picture in the x-axis.
[image]

The thing is that if I use greater values, then the axis labeling should not start with 0, right? Does someone have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @Slaw I think the biggest problem is that Im using CategoryAxis and the resulting overlapping. Actually I don't need to set the categories manual like "Category1", "Category2" and so on. Is there a possiblllity to get rid of the overlapping without manually writing the categories?

Comment: @Slaw what do you mean by that? I do not have any animation functionality in my project

Comment: thanks a lot. that worked.

Comment: @Slaw if I use large values for the interval, then the x,y label in the lower left always starts with (0/0). Do you know if there is a possibility to make this scalable? that means, if I use large values for the interval, that it won't start with (0/0) but with appropriate values. THX in advance!

Comment: Alright, I feel kinda stupid for not remembering this property exists: Set the [`NumberAxis#forceZeroInRange`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#forceZeroInRangeProperty) property to `false`. You should be able to continue using the auto-range functionality afterwards.

Comment: @Slaw what can I say ... thanks a lot! your hints helped me a lot! does there exist a instruction similar to setForceZeroInRange() for Category Axis? Thank you very much!

Comment: Not that I know of. Unlike number axes, a category axis does not have a lower and upper bound, but you can check the documentation to be sure

Comment: @Slaw ok, anyway thanks for all your help!